# How avoid java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exception, search

I'm using `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`  as I noticed when I set  this `app:iconifiedByDefault="false"`  property in my searchView  app throws  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()' on a null object reference` is there a way to avoid throwing this exception?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="15dp"
        tools:context=".navigation.home.search.GameSearchFragment">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/searchToolbar"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@color/primaryColor"
                app:defaultQueryHint="Search Games"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:theme="@style/SearchStyle"
                app:searchIcon="@null"
                app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/searchViewBorder"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/searchToolbar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/searchToolbar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchToolbar">

        </View>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem. Please could you consider editing your initial question in order to remove detail that turned out to be not important?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it, The problem  was that I used theme style in search View and style was inherited from EditTextView I changed it to SearchView  And problem was fixed

Before - `<style name="SearchStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">`
After - `<style name="SearchStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use android:iconifiedByDefault="false" not app:iconifiedByDefault.
If it does not work, share your java or Kotlin code please

Comment: no that was not the case, I wrote below answer, btw thank you